git shortlog does not find commits after a certain date
I'm trying to get recent statistics about authors of a github repository.
Using git shortlog works fine, as recommended here for instance, but for some reason it stops finding commits after September 2023.
If I search for myself, I get 0 results for this, although I know quite well that I have authored/commited after this point.
git shortlog --all --author=Nury --after=2023-10-01 

What am I missing here? What could make the count stop, and is there a way to find the most recent commits by author?

I cannot reproduce with a fresh clone. With the command from the question, I get 11 commits by Elisa Nury after 2023-10-01. Have you fetched all commits from the remote before running the command?

Yes, indeed I have, but I had been using Github Desktop... so maybe it is a problem with Github Desktop. I'll try fetching directly from git bash, thanks for your input!
